# Mysterious action on page in iOS WKWebView, which doesn't trigger any callbacks

Tags: wkwebview

I have a web page with a button which triggers some action and I want to show "back" button on the UI when the web view can go back. This action is handled properly by desktop browser and swiping gestures on the webview (i.e. browser shows the back button and swiping back works properly). But for some reason, this action doesn't trigger any WKNavigationDelegate callbacks. Webview and following callbacks look to be setup properly in the VC:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self


decidePolicyForNavigationAction
didStartProvisionalNavigation
didFinishNavigation
didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation
didFailNavigation
didCommitNavigation
webViewWebContentProcessDidTerminate
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge
didFailProvisionalNavigation
```

Even using observer for "loading" property of the web view doesn't work:

```
webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "loading", options: .New, context: nil)

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    guard let _ = object as? WKWebView else { return }
    guard let keyPath = keyPath else { return }
    guard let change = change else { return }
    switch keyPath {
    case "loading":
        // Set button
    default:break
}
```

Callbacks for other actions on the same website work properly.
What can be the reason for this?